# Automatically display a div once all radio button sets have answers

Tags: jquery

I've been stuck on this problem for quite some time to the point that I've moved on and finished experimenting with coding other quiz styles ala-Buzzfeed. Now, the logic goes, "Once a radio button in all of the radio button sets are clicked, show the div"

I've "somewhat" solved this problem by cheating my way to it, a.k.a by making a button which listens when a radio button in all sets are clicked. But, that's not what I want to happen.

Help?

```
//PART OF THE CODE GOES...

//RESULTS ALGORITHM 
$('#submit').click(function() { 

    var choice1 = 0;
    var choice2 = 0;
    var choice3 = 0;
    var choice4 = 0;
    var choice5 = 0;
    var choice6 = 0;

    $('input[type=radio]').prop('disabled', true);  

    //REQUIRES ANSWERS TO ALL QUESTIONS
    if (($("input[name='qa4']:checked").length == "0") ||
    ($("input[name='qa5']:checked").length == "0")){
        alert("Please answer all questions.");
    }

    else{
        //TABULATE THE RESULTS OF ANSWERS
        switch(parseInt($("input[name='qa1']:checked").val())){
            case 1: choice1++; break;
            case 2: choice2++; break;
            case 3: choice3++; break;
            case 4: choice4++; break;
            case 5: choice5++; break;
            case 6: choice6++; break;
        }
```

Full Code Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/djleonardo/m4Jcb/

Comment: I have seen your JS code... You're doing it all the verbose and hardest possible way... You need to learn how to use JS in a more (fun) methodic, dynamic and programmatic way.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Hey! Yeah, I realized that. It's pretty inefficient, but I'm trying. Hoping I could learn through optimizing my messy code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by enclosing your `.click()` inside a function `giveResults()` that will be called from a `.click()` event on the `.a-choice` once every input is `:checked` ;)

[Fixed JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m4Jcb/1/)

Comment: Wow. Okay... maybe I should expand my almost non-existent javascript knowledge. Thanks!

Comment: It's just the need to exercise, as always ;)

Comment: You could merge it with the `if(!$("input[name^=qa]:not(:checked)").length)` that @600mhz suggested. It would be a cleaner solution other than specifying every single input name.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("input[name^=qa]").on('change', function() {
    if(!$("input[name^=qa]:not(:checked)").length) {
        //all input box that name begin with "qa" checked
        $('div#id').show();
    } else {
        // do some stuff here while it's not all checked.
    }
});
```